# InflateException в проекте android wear

Tags: android, android-wear

Вставляю в разметку круглую кнопку. после чего приложение падает в вот таким меседжем:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.support.wearable.view.CircularButton

02-09 18:44:38.395 4344-4344/com.root.englishfor E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.wearable.view.CircularButton.setRippleColor

02-09 18:44:38.395 4344-4344/com.root.englishfor E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.animation.StateListAnimator', referenced from method android.support.wearable.view.CircularButton.setPressedTranslationZ
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        app:layout_box="all" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_box="all" />

    <android.support.wearable.view.CircularButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Comment: А библиотека нужная добавлена?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну я тоже об этом подумал,     compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'  эта же библиотека?

Comment: А вот это есть `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'

Comment: Думаю, дело в том, что ребёнок у `BoxInsetLayout` может быть только один. Попробуйте поместить всё, что внутри него в `LinearLayout` например.

Comment: Либо пропущен у `CircularButton` аттрибут `app:layout_box="all"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб попробовал оба варианта. ошибка та же. заметил в логах  еще пару строк. щас обновлю вопрос

Comment: Видать у вас `suppot-appcompat-v7` не подключена)

Comment: зависимость для часов должно выглядеть так же само как и для телефона     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1' или
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' ?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб попробовал запустить на 5.0.1 ошибка пропала. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Библиотеки лучше обе добавить. А на 5 запускается, т.к. требует для запуска классы `RippleDrawable` и `StateListAnimator`. В принципе, т.к. на часах, наверное, только с 5 андроида ОСь начинается, можно просто эту разметку в `res/layout-v21` положить...